# Access Azure block blob storage from spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, ssl, netty, azure-blob-storage

**UPDATE**
I used the client to upload files to an existing blob. The first file gets uploaded successfully but the program would print the same SslHandler debugging messages about Handshaking. For me, this means that the client can communicate with Azure, execute operations but it can't get the response back. In my code I use the blockingGet() method to wait for a response from Azure, Apparently something blocks Azure from sending back the response to the caller. I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: The source did not signal an event for 60 seconds and has been terminated.
    at io.reactivex.internal.util.ExceptionHelper.wrapOrThrow(ExceptionHelper.java:46)
    at io.reactivex.internal.observers.BlockingMultiObserver.blockingGet(BlockingMultiObserver.java:93)
    at io.reactivex.Single.blockingGet(Single.java:2700)
    at azure.AzureBlockBlobClient.createContainer(AzureBlockBlobClient.java:68)
    at spark.AzureExample.<init>(AzureExample.java:18)
    at spark.AzureExample.main(AzureExample.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
```

---

I have written some code that connects to my Azure blob storage account and create a container.

If I run it as a main class directly from a jar or simply running the class file from my Intellij IDE, it works. If I run it from a spark-submit command passing the class to run and the jar, it does not work. I get the following exception:

```
2108 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-1] DEBUG io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler  - [id: 0xa1cbec16, L:/10.19.117.127:56010 - R:storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/20.138.98.132:443] HANDSHAKEN: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
65718 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] DEBUG io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler  - [id: 0xdd8a9177, L:/10.19.117.127:56019 - R:storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/20.138.98.132:443] HANDSHAKEN: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
137718 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-5] DEBUG io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler  - [id: 0xffca3cfa, L:/10.19.117.127:56022 - R:storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/20.138.98.132:443] HANDSHAKEN: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
225794 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-7] DEBUG io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler  - [id: 0xb957ab94, L:/10.19.117.127:56030 - R:storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/20.138.98.132:443] HANDSHAKEN: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: The source did not signal an event for 60 seconds and has been terminated.
    at io.reactivex.internal.util.ExceptionHelper.wrapOrThrow(ExceptionHelper.java:46)
    at io.reactivex.internal.observers.BlockingMultiObserver.blockingGet(BlockingMultiObserver.java:93)
    at io.reactivex.Single.blockingGet(Single.java:2700)
    at AzureBlockBlobClient.createContainer(AzureBlockBlobClient.java:58)
    at DataExtractor.<init>(DataExtractor.java:69)
    at DataExtractor.main(DataExtractor.java:355)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:849)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

When it works, it just prints a line similar to this line once then continue execution:

```
2108 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-1] DEBUG io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler  - [id: 0xa1cbec16, L:/10.19.117.127:56010 - R:storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/20.138.98.132:443] HANDSHAKEN: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
```

When I run it on spark, it prints those 4 lines from SslHandler -a minute or so of waiting between each line- and then throws the exception.

```
2108 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-1] DEBUG io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler  - [id: 0xa1cbec16, L:/10.19.117.127:56010 - R:storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/20.138.98.132:443] HANDSHAKEN: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
65718 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] DEBUG io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler  - [id: 0xdd8a9177, L:/10.19.117.127:56019 - R:storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/20.138.98.132:443] HANDSHAKEN: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
137718 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-5] DEBUG io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler  - [id: 0xffca3cfa, L:/10.19.117.127:56022 - R:storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/20.138.98.132:443] HANDSHAKEN: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
225794 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-7] DEBUG io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler  - [id: 0xb957ab94, L:/10.19.117.127:56030 - R:storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/20.138.98.132:443] HANDSHAKEN: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
```

Here are some snippets of my code:

This is the code of my client that connects to Azure:

```
public AzureBlockBlobClient(String accountName, String accountKey, String containerName) {
    this.accountName = accountName;
    this.accountKey = accountKey;
    this.containerName = containerName;
    init();
}

private void init() {
    log.info("Init AzureBlockBlobClient started...");
    try {
        SharedKeyCredentials creds = new SharedKeyCredentials(accountName, accountKey);
        serviceURL = new ServiceURL(new URL("https://" + accountName + ".blob.core.windows.net/"),
            StorageURL.createPipeline(creds, new PipelineOptions()));
        containerURL = serviceURL.createContainerURL(containerName);
    }catch (InvalidKeyException e){
        log.error("Authentication error while trying to access storage account", e);
    }catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        log.error("Invalid Service URL", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.error("Error initializing AzureBlockBlobClient", e);
    }

    log.info("Init AzureBlockBlobClient Done!");
}

public void createContainer(){
    try {
        // Let's create a container using a blocking call to Azure Storage
        // If container exists, we'll catch and continue
        log.info("Creating container {}." , containerName);
        ContainerCreateResponse response = containerURL.create(null, null, null).blockingGet();
        log.info("Container Create Response was {}." , response.statusCode());
    }
    catch (RestException e){
        if (e instanceof RestException && e.response().statusCode() != 409) {
            log.error("Error Creating container", e);
        } else {
            log.info("Container {} already exists, resuming...", containerName);
        }
    }
}
```

This is where I actually make a call to create a container:

```
private AzureBlockBlobClient azureBlockBlobClient;

public AzureExample() {
    azureBlockBlobClient = new AzureBlockBlobClient(AzureConf.ACCOUNT_NAME,AzureConf.ACCOUNT_KEY, AzureConf.CONTAINER_NAME);
    azureBlockBlobClient.createContainer();
}

public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    new AzureExample();
    System.exit(0);
}
```

And this is where my constants are:

```
public interface AzureConf {
String ACCOUNT_KEY ="<SomeAccountKey>";
String ACCOUNT_NAME = "storage";
String CONTAINER_NAME = "My-container";
}
```

This is my maven pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>examples</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-azure-storage</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-azure</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-storage</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
        <version>10.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.reactivex.rxjava2</groupId>
        <artifactId>rxjava</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor -->


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.rest.v2</groupId>
        <artifactId>client-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <!--I have to exclude following dependencies and include version 2.9.7 of them otherwise I get
        SoSuchMethodError-->
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>reference.conf</resource>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer"></transformer>
                </transformers>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Any idea why this isn't working? Is it a handshaking between netty and Azure that doesn't go in both directions?